# WordPress CRON job working when reloading the page

Tags: wp-cron

I'm Trying to scheduling wp_cron job in my website to send email everyday without opening my website but this is not happening. This work when user come to the website or reload a page.

Here is my code to scheduling cron job

```
// WP_CRON Scheduling

function my_custom_cron_schedule( $schedules ) {
    $schedules['every_one_minute'] = array(
        'interval' => 60, // Every 1 Minute
        'display'  => __( 'Every 1 Minute' ),
    );
    return $schedules;
}
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'my_custom_cron_schedule' );



//Schedule an action if it's not already scheduled
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'my_cron_function_hook' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( current_time('timestamp'), 'every_one_minute', 'my_cron_function_hook' );
}

///Hook into that action that'll fire every One Minute
 add_action( 'my_cron_function_hook', 'my_cron_function' );

//create your function, that runs on cron
function my_cron_function() {
    $crtime = date('F-j-Y h:i:s');
    wp_mail('abc@example.com','Cron Job Test', "$crtime");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress Cron Jobs are not "real" Cronjobs, instead they relie on somebody visiting the site, then looking if it's time to do scheduled jobs.

1.: Someone visits the website

2.: Wordpress calls the file wp-cron.php

3.: wp-cron.php looks into the database if there are scheduled jobs that are due at this time.

4.: wp-cron.php does all of the scheduled jobs.

---

If you want to make sure that your cronjob is executed on time, you need to do some more steps:

1.: Schedule your cronjob. You did that already.

2.: disable the integrated Wordpress-Cron. Edit your wp-config.php and insert `define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);` below the line `define('DB_COLLATE','');`

3.: Create a "real" cronjob on your server, set to run every so often (5 Minutes, 15 Minutes, 1 Minute, something like that). I don't know if and how you can create a cronjob on your hosting, that's something you got to ask your hosting company. Make the target of your cronjob yourdomain.com/wp-cron.php

4.: Success! Your cron should work now as intended!

Happy Coding!